# .ASHX file need to do a IF ELSE Statement within it

Tags: vb.net

I am using an Upload script (http://www.uploadify.com/demos/ ) Converted to VB.NET for uploading multiple images. This script I have been using for years. It is very robust and works well. However, when I am working on it locally, I have to go inside of the ASHX file and comment out the LIVE database and uncomment the Local Database server.

My question is the following: Is there a way to do an IF ELSE statement inside of the ASHX file? I have tried and it errors out.

What I would like to do is something like this.

```
if Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")="192.168.2.12" then
'local connection here
else
'live server connection here
end if
```

This will make it so I can work on the scripts, without having to change this ALL THE TIME... It is right annoying.

Any idea's?

Answer (score 0):

There is an IsLocal property you can read, which will tell you if the current request is being called locally. Assuming you are running within the ProcessRequest of the .ASHX

```
    Dim isLocal As Boolean = context.Request.IsLocal

    If isLocal Then
        'local connection here
    Else
        'live server connection here
    End If
```

Comment: I am trying it, but it is not working. In Google Chrome Console, it states : 500 (Internal Server Error) ...........When I remove the code, it works like it supposed to.

Comment: You stated, as long as it is running in the ProcessRequest. And it is. It is running in this...............Public Sub ProcessRequest

Comment: I ran the script itself, and it is not seeing the connection.

Dim isLocal As Boolean = context.Request.IsLocal
If isLocal Then
'local connection here
else     
'live server connection here
end if 
  
cn.Open()  '<-- Right here, Name 'cn' is not declared.

Comment: I just read something, and it makes a lot of sense. Using this script isLocal. Isn't ALL servers LOCAL? So, how is the script going to tell that it is a local or a live server?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured it out. I used another method that I am using in an aspx.vb file. And I changed it up a little to work within the ASHX file. Works like a charm.

```
dim ipAdd as string
dim dbName as string
dim UN as string
dim PW as string

dim theLocal as string = Httpcontext.Current.Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME")
if theLocal="192.168.2.12" then
ipAdd = "LOCAL_SERVER_NAME\INSTANCE_NAME"
dbName = "LOCAL_DB_NAME"
UN = "LOCAL_USERNAME"
PW = "LOCAL_PASSWORD"
else
ipAdd = "00.00.00.00"
dbName = "LIVE_DB_NAME"
UN = "SERVER_USERNMAE"
PW = "SERVER_PASSWORD"
end if

Dim cn As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source="+ipAdd+"; Initial Catalog="+dbName+";User ID="+UN+";Password="+PW+";")
cn.Open()
```

Thanks for the attempted assistance from Malcor.
This is a wrap all.

Wayne